# I am creating a menu swing application, I used a splitpane and the right component to import various jpanel

Tags: java, swing, splitpane

I am creating a menu swing application, I used a splitpane and the right component to import various jpanel. Once I click the home panel buttion, the other jpanel are not loading if I press the coressponding buttion

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Mainframe extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Mainframe
     */
    
    



    int n=0;

    public Mainframe() {
        initComponents();
    
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        SplitPane = new javax.swing.JSplitPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        workpanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        jButton2.setText("Home");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton3.setText("Back");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(0, 28, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(391, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(225, 225, 225))
        );

        SplitPane.setLeftComponent(jPanel2);

        jButton4.setText("User");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Admin");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout workpanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(workpanel);
        workpanel.setLayout(workpanelLayout);
        workpanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            workpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(workpanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(403, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(workpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, workpanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addGap(274, 274, 274))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, workpanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton5)
                        .addGap(259, 259, 259))))
        );
        workpanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            workpanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(workpanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(245, 245, 245)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addGap(112, 112, 112)
                .addComponent(jButton5)
                .addContainerGap(237, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        SplitPane.setRightComponent(workpanel);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(SplitPane)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(SplitPane)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Userjpanel user = new Userjpanel();
        SplitPane.setRightComponent(user);
        
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        AdminJpanel add = new AdminJpanel();
        SplitPane.setRightComponent(add);
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Mainframe home = new Mainframe();
        SplitPane.setRightComponent(home.workpanel);
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Userjpanel user = new Userjpanel();
        SplitPane.setRightComponent(user);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Mainframe.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
            new Mainframe().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JSplitPane SplitPane;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel workpanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

The code above is what I have used

Comment: You need to revalidate and repaint the container after adding or removing components. But *really* you will want to use a CardLayout to swap components.

Comment: While the above advice is generally good, it does not apply when using a JSplitPane. You do not need to directly invoke revalidate() and repaint() when using the methods of the split pane to change the components. The split pane will do the revalidate() and repaint() for you. Therefore the question was reopened since the linked duplicates do not apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mainframe home = new Mainframe();
SplitPane.setRightComponent(home.workpanel);
```

In your "Back" button logic don't keep creating a new instance of you "Mainframe" class. You only ever need one instance of the frame.

You just need to access your "workpanel" instance in your class:

```
//Mainframe home = new Mainframe();
//SplitPane.setRightComponent(home.workpanel);
SplitPane.setRightComponent(workpanel);
```

Also, variable names should NOT start with a upper case character. Learn and follow Java naming conventions.